# Group topology induced by group action

Tags: general-topology, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, $X$ a topological space and $G\times X \longrightarrow X$ a group action so that $\begin{align*}
X\longrightarrow X \\
x \mapsto g\cdot x
\end{align*}$ is a homeomorphism $\forall g \in G$. Is there a coarsest topology on $G$ so that:

1. $G$ is a topological group
2. The group action is continuous

?

I have showed that the topology induced by the maps $\begin{align*} G \longrightarrow X \\
g\mapsto g\cdot x\end{align*}$ and
$\begin{align*} G \longrightarrow X \\
g\mapsto g^{-1}\cdot x\end{align*}$ $\forall x\in X$ makes inversion, left action and right action continuous on $G$.

Comment: Take the coarsest topology on $G$ such that each member of $\{\phi_x:G\to Gx: g\to gx\}$  is continuous, where we give each orbit $Gx$ the subspace topology.

Comment: I think that is the same topology as the one I suggested. I am struggling to show that the group operation is continuous

Comment: This will [automatically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_topology#General_case) give a topology. Youare declaring the opens in $G$ to be inverse images of the opens in $Gx$

Comment: Yes. But does it make $G$ a topological group?

Comment: Rasumus, you should write your first comment above as part of your question rather than just putting a big question mark.

Comment: Sorry I misread your question. I don't think you can show that $G$ is a topological group without more information. To prove $\times$ continuous, you pick a $\phi_x$ and consider $(\phi_x\circ \times)^{-1}(W)$ for some open set $W$ in $Gx$. This is $\{(g,h)\in G\times G:\phi_x\circ \times(g,h)\in W\}=\{(g,h):ghx\in W\}.$ So, we need to show that this set is open in $G\times G.$ So pick $(g,h)$ in this set. We should find opens $g\in U,h\in V$ in $G$ such that $(g',h')\in U\times V\Rightarrow g'h'x\in W.$ But without knowing anything more about $\times$ there is no way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is hausdorff and has compact and connected neighbourhoods around each point, the answer is the topology induced by the homomorphism $G\longrightarrow \text{Homeo}(X)$ defined by the group action, where $\text{Homeo}(X)$ is the homeomorphism group equipped with the compact-open-topology. To prove it:

Let $\tau$ be a topology on $G$ so that $G$ is a topological group and the group action $G\times X\longrightarrow X$ is continuous. Since $X$ is hausdorff and locally compact, the exponential object $X^X$ exists in the category $\text{Top}$. By the universal property of exponential objects $\exists!$ continuous $G \overset{\phi }{\longrightarrow} X^X$ so that
[image]

commutes. $X^X$ can be constructed as $X^X=C(X,X)$ equipped with the compact-open-topology. $\text{Homeo}(X)\subseteq X^X$. $\text{Im }\phi\subseteq\text{Homeo}(X)$. $G\overset{\phi}{\longrightarrow}\text{Homeo}(X)$ is precisely the homomorphism defined by the group action. There's a theorem stating that if $X$ is hausdorff and has compact and connected neighbourhoods around each point, $\text{Homeo}(X)$ equipped with the compact-open-topology is a topological group https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/30037630.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3A0a25ff84e89d996eeaf57120097c8447. Define $\tau_i$ to be the topology on $G$ induced by $G\overset{\phi}{\longrightarrow}\text{Homeo}(X)$. Then $(G,\tau_i)$ is a topological group from the universl property of induced topology and since $\phi$ is a homomorphism. Since $(G,\tau)\overset{\phi}{\longrightarrow} \text{Homeo}(X)$ is continuous, $\tau_i\subseteq \tau$. That means $\tau_i$ is the coarsest topology so the action is continuous and $G$ is a topological group.